# is there python example of 'ContinueRequest' for ExactTarget FUEL SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I am looking for a python example of `"ContinueRequest" I only found .NET and PHP here https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-more-than-2500-records-using-the-continuerequest-property.html

Thank you in advance. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example which illustrates this at:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/objsamples/sample_clickevent.py